Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Ref<SVGSVGElement> | undefined'
next build

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.4
  - Environments: .env

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
   Linting and checking validity of types  ...Failed to compile.

./components/sections/navbar/horizontal/index.tsx:34:38
Type error: Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<Pick<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>, "string" | "cy" | "fr" | "fy" | "id" | "to" | "type" | "name" | "version" | "style" | "key" | "clipPath" | "filter" | ... 458 more ... | "zoomAndPan"> & { ...; } & RefAttributes<...>>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>'.
  Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<Pick<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>, "string" | "cy" | "fr" | "fy" | "id" | "to" | "type" | "name" | "version" | "style" | "key" | "clipPath" | "filter" | ... 458 more ... | "zoomAndPan"> & { ...; } & RefAttributes<...>>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>' is not assignable to type 'Pick<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>, "string" | "cy" | "fr" | "fy" | "id" | "to" | "type" | "name" | "version" | "style" | "key" | "clipPath" | "filter" | "mask" | ... 457 more ... | "zoomAndPan"> & { ...; } & RefAttributes<...>'.
        Type 'SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefAttributes<SVGSVGElement>'.
          Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
            Type 'LegacyRef<SVGSVGElement> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Ref<SVGSVGElement> | undefined'.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Ref<SVGSVGElement> | undefined'.

  32 |       <Links>
  33 |         {list.map(({ id, href, Icon }) => (
> 34 |           <Link key={id} href={href} Icon={Icon} />
     |                                      ^
  35 |         ))}
  36 |       </Links>
  37 |     </nav>

Trying to build a production version using npm run build, but after compiling successfully it fails on Linting and checking validity of types.
Using npm run dev works and it runs without any issues.

the error is really on the first line...

@DanielA.White Do you mean line 33 ?

no of the. e. error message block
